# How does @Html.BeginForm() works?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm very new to ASP.NET, just started the MVC tutorial today on asp.net. I got here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view

So far so good, the problem:

In my View I have the following code
(Model is set to the view with @model MyFirstMVC4.Models.Movie)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Movie</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        //... bla bla html input
        <p>
             <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

My MovieController

```
    // Shows the view
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
        if (movie == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(movie);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Movie/Edit/5

    [HttpPost] // Handles the view above
    public ActionResult Edit(Movie movie)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(movie).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(movie);
    }
```

And here is the question - How the heck does it pass the Movie object to the POST method above?! When I observe the client side there is

```
<form action = "/Movie/Edit/1" ... />
```

Here I don't understand why action = url of the very same view page?!1
Also on the server side there is just Html.BeginForm() :(
How does it realize to what action method to post and what route parameters to pass?
It works, I just don't know why

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The version of `BeginForm` in the code,
with no parameters, sends an HTTP POST to the current URL, so if the view is a response to
`/Movie/Edit/5`, the opening form tag will look like the following:
`< form action="/Movie/Edit/5" method="post">`

The BeginForm HTML helper asks the routing engine how to reach the Edit action of the
MovieController. Behind the scenes it uses the method named GetVirtualPath on the Routes
property exposed by RouteTable — that’s where your web application registered all its routes in
global.asax. If you did all this without an HTML helper, you’d have to write all the following
code:

```
  @{
 var context = this.ViewContext.RequestContext;
  var values = new RouteValueDictionary{
  { "controller", "movie" }, { "action", "edit" }
 };
  var path = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(context, values);
 }
 <form action="@path.VirtualPath" method="get">
  ...
 </form>
```

You asked how is movie object is passed. That is called **model binding**.
When you have an action with a parameter, the MVC runtime uses a model binder to build the
parameter. You can have multiple model binders registered in the MVC runtime for different types
of models, but the workhorse by default will be the `DefaultModelBinder`.

In the case of an Movie
object, the default model binder inspects the Movie and finds all the movie properties available
for binding. Following the naming convention you examined earlier, the default model binder can automatically convert and move values from the request into an movie object (the model binder can
also create an instance of the object to populate).
In other words, when the model binder sees an Movie has a Title property, it looks for a value
named “Title” in the request. Notice the model binder looks “in the request” and not “in the form
collection.” The model binder uses components known as value providers to search for values in
different areas of a request.
 The model binder can look at route data, the query string, and the form
collection, and you can add custom value providers if you so desire.

Comment: Playing around with overrides for `@Html.BeginForm` - I supplied `Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Movies", FormMethod.Post)`. Notice I did not supply the third `id` part of the route. Yet in the resulting markup, it is there: `/Movies/Edit/4`. How does it do this? If I suppy `Html.BeginForm("Delete", "Movies", FormMethod.Post)`, the resulting HTML does not have the `id`: `/Movies/Delete`.

Answer (score 10):

When you call `BeginForm()` without any parameters it default to using the same controller/action used to render the current page. It assumes you'll have an action with the correct name on your controller that will accept postbacks (which you do). It uses the `RouteValues` to do this.

It automatically binds each input control (by name) to the parameters of the action accepting the postback - or in your case, the properties of the object parameter for the action accepting the postback.

Answer (score 4):

`[HttpPost]` attribute is given to the action that you want to be called on the POST submit of the form.

to understand how `@using (Html.BeginForm())`  works , you need to know what page it is already on . using `@using (Html.BeginForm())` in 2 different views will come back to two different controllers

Answer (score 0):

We can create forms by typing simple html or by html helpers. 
One of them Html.BeginForm(); it is a little bit odd because you actually can wrap it in a using statement because  this particular helper returns an object that implements IDisposable in C#.  First it writes out  with opening tag. And at the bottom when the generated code calls dispose on that object, that’s when it will write out closing form tag . So BeginForm gives me an object that will write out my opening form tag and my closing from tag. After that you don't worry about anything you can just focus on labels and inputs