# How does MVC handle button clicks in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

How does MVC handle the submit button in my code? I have a controller named ArticleController which should handle it, but I can't figure out how.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Article</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Text, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Text, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

The controller looks like this:

```
namespace Decision.Controllers
{
  public class ArticleController : Controller
  {
    // GET: Article
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var article = new ArticleController();
        var home = new HomeController();
        return View(home);
    }

    /*[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Article article)
    {
        entities.Article.AddObject(article);
        entities.SaveChanges();

        return Redirect("/");
    }*/
  }
}
```

Which method handles the submit button when clicked?

Comment: Your controller need a `Index()` method marked with `[HttpPost]` and it should include a parameter for the model you use in the view (which will be bound with the values of the form controls (and as a side note, the code in your `Create()` GET method makes no sense - you do not initialize instances of the controllers)

Comment: Just use `@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Article", FormMethod.Post))` and `[HttpPost]` in second `Create` method. You don't need to handle submit button click event, the form automatically call the controller action method given in context.

Comment: Well, if you remove verb filter and make `article` an optional parameter `public ActionResult Create(Article article = null)` then you can use this method for both `get` and `post` requests. You can check iif article is `null` then return View, and if it is not - proceed with BL to save it. But this is rather an unusual way of working with MVC controller.

Answer (score 1):

The HttpPost controller normally handles it but you have that commented out for some reason? You need to mark you BeignForm with some information i.e.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Article", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "insert any css class here", role = "form" }))
{
```

Comment: it didnt work together with the httpget. In an article i looked at they used both but in my code they both dont go along with eachother, so my httppost would handle the button?

Comment: Try to update your begin form to something like the edited answer.

Comment: The application searches for a site called Create that it doesnt find when I press the button. How do I call the function Create inside the Controller.

Comment: Try taking the Value = "Create" out of your submit button. Also make sure your HttpPost is not commented out

Comment: It goes into the HttpPost method, How can I get the EditorFor Text? And is it usual to open the context in that httppost method to write the data into the database or how do you usually do it?

Comment: I would normally do everything using the MVC format. So the context would never be exposed in the controller. It would be called in a repository.

Answer (score 1):

So, in pure HTML you need to have a submit button inside a form that has post method.

```
 <form action = "" method = "post">
        <input type="submit" name="x" value="x" />
 </form>
```

BeginForm extension uses by default the post method.

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper
)
```

To understand how to use BeginForm extension you can read more here: 
[How does @Html.BeginForm() works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744191/how-does-html-beginform-works)

Your main problem looks to be the following:

> to understand how @using (Html.BeginForm()) works, you need to know
>   what page it is already on . using @using (Html.BeginForm()) in 2
>   different views will come back to two different controllers

First you can check what action gets generated in your HTML when you render the form:  `<form action = "" method = "post">`.

Then you must know that you have the possibility to pass the executed action/controller to BeginForm extension method.

For example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Article", FormMethod.Post))
{
  @* *@ 
}
```

Comment: How do you pass the text I enter into that EditorFor field as paramters?

Comment: Model Binding. You need to have a Text property in the class that you're expecting as a request (in that HTTPPOST action).

Comment: Here you have more about model binding (property level): http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/model-binding-in-asp.net-mvc

Comment: And here you have more about model binding (if you need to bind collections): http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Answer (score 1):

please have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods for a clear idea about request methods.

When a user views a page, that's a GET request and when a user submits a form, that's usually a POST request. HttpGet and HttpPost just restrict the action to the applicable request type.

When you add [HttpPost] to the action, MVC clearly knows which action to use to handle POST request.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are in index view. You need to change `BeginForm` to

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Article")) 
{
    <<your stuff>>
}
```

and uncomment post method.