# Call Method with argument when button Clicked

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Razor Template to create a web app, that i can use to start and stop services through.
I have a text box,in which i can feed in service and a Start and Stop button

```
<div>

        <form>
            Service Name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="servicename"><br>
            <button onclick=@Model.StartService("servicename")>Start</button>   <button onclick=@Model.StopService("servicename")>Start</button>
        </form>
</div>
```

I have a Model that has the stop and Start service Method that takes in the service name as the argument.
Running my app automaically calls the StartService and StopService. I want them to be invoked only when the button is clicked

Here is my model

```
public  string StopService(string serviceName)
{
    ServiceController[] controller = ServiceController.GetServices(serviceName);
    if (controller == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    controller[0].Stop();
    controller[0].WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
    return controller[0].Status.ToString();
}

public  string StartService(string serviceName)
{
    ServiceController[] controller = ServiceController.GetServices(serviceName);
    if (controller == null)
    {
        return null ;
    }

    controller[0].Start();
    controller[0].WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
    return controller[0].Status.ToString();
}
```

I could be doing it all wrong but i am very new to this. I want to achieve this through the suggested the web template (ie., using Razor Page)

Comment: An example of using jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048778/asp-net-mvc-actionlink-and-post-method

Comment: It seems like you don't need jQuery, you can just use the basic form submit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16744191/how-does-html-beginform-works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the concept of client-server here. Your `StartService` and `StopService` methods exist server-side, but `onclick` only means anything client-side, and specifically the actual click by the user that would activate it happens client-side. You cannot directly call some server-side method like you're attempting to do client-side. In fact, all that's happening here is that Razor is actually running your `StartService` and `StopService` methods during rendering of the view in order to try to fill the `onclick` attributes with the return values. So the end result is that your HTML will look like `onclick="Started"`, where "Started" is perhaps one of your `Status` values.

Long and short, if you need to activate something on the server when a use clicks a button, you must submit a request to the server. That can be done via a traditional form post (which will cause the page to refresh) or via AJAX. In either case, you would post to a route with a handler that would then start/stop your service.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how you said can be achieved? @Chris Pratt